# Creating folders in a Visual Studio Installer Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I've built a Visual Studio (2010) Installer Setup project to deploy a basic WinForms app and I need my installer to create a couple of directories based on the OS that its running on.  For example, when the installer is run on Windows XP (and earlier), I need to create:

```
Application Folder\NewFolder
```

If the installer is running on Vista or later, I need to create the directory below the Common Application Data Folder (i.e., C:\ProgramData) like this:

```
Common Application Data Folder\NewFolder
```

I see that I can add a "Custom Folder" via View -> "File System" but I'm not sure how to declare the DefaultLocation property for this new folder.  It defaults to a value of [TARGETDIR] but I'm uncertain how to specify the location of the directory that I want to create.  Can this be done with a Visual Studio Installer Setup project or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this working by adding both folder locations to my setup project via View -> File System.  Then I specified a Condition for each folder.  For the folder I want to create on XP, I used "WindowsBuild < 6000" and for the Vista/Windows 7 folder, I used "WindowsBuild >= 6000".

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported by Visual Studio setup projects.

Other setup authoring tools support this through a [type 51 custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (property set with formatted text).

Basically, your default TARGETDIR can point to one location and a type 51 custom action can change it to another location during install. This custom action can be [conditioned with VersionNT property](http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/install-resources-windows-ver/).

Answer (score 0):

On your Special Folder, you can set the DefaultLocation to [CommonAppDataFolder].

On XP, this will resolve to c:\documents and settings\all users\application data

And on Win 7, this will resolve to c:\ProgramData